# Bash on android

Tags: bash, android, bash-scripting

I have a rooted sony z2 smartphone and I'm able to run sh scripts, I also have busybox installed but I'm unable to work out how to run bash scripts,  I've tried ls -l /bin/bash from terminal and get no folder or files found can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have an ARM `bash` binary in `/system/xbin`.  It will need to be a statically compiled binary since the libraries it typically expects won't be on your phone.  `bash` isn't part of Android.

Alternatively you can setup a Debian chroot and use `bash` within that.

Also, you could search "bash" on the appstore and try installing one of the apps that come up.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after looking thru system/xbin I have found bash, haven't tested yet but at least it's there, could you talk me thru setting up a debian chroot ? I've seen the term chroot around but have no knowledge of it

Comment: Not enough time or room here, but there's apps that do it for you.

Comment: OK I'll get googling, you know a app of hand? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: I've used this - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.galoula.LinuxInstall&hl=en

Comment: Thanks will try it out, had a quick Google I know roughly what you mean now, I've tried linux deploy but kept getting errors so removed it hopefully more luck on this!